# Swift Playground: Indexing a List within a class gives an error

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I tried the following in Swift Playground:

```
class C {

    init(test: Integer) {
        let simpleList:String[] = ["A","B","C"]
        simpleList[test]
        println(simpleList[test])
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> Could not find an overload for subscript that accepts the supplied
>   arguments

This pops up in multiple places when I try to index a list.

Comment: Change `test` to the `Int` type so: `(test: Int)`. Try not to mix Swift types and ObjC types too much

Comment: It worked. Will be careful moving forward. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are usually two causes for this error:

In your case, you need to change `test` to the `Int` type like this: `(test: Int)`.

Another case that throws a similar error is due to `simpleList` being of type `Any` or `AnyObject`.

In cases like those you need to cast it to type `String[]` or another Swift array type before indexing